# Login com SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, login

Eu estou tentando criar um sistema de login, com SQL server, usando Visual Studio e C#.

Mas mesmo com tudo certo, e os logins setados no banco de dados, ainda assim dá ''login incorreto''

códigos de exemplo abaixo.

```
public bool tem = false;
    public String mensagem = "";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    Conexão con = new Conexão();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public bool verificarLogin(String login, String senha)
    {
        //Procurar no banco esse login e senha
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from logins where email = @login and senha = @senha";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = con.Conectar();
           dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows) // se foi encontrado    
            {
                tem = true;
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {

            this.mensagem = "Erro no banco de dados";
        }
        return tem;
    }




    public String cadastrar(String email, String Senha, String confSenha)
    {
        //comandos para inserir
        return mensagem;
    }
}
```

}

```
private void entrarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controle controle = new Controle();
        controle.acessar(txbLogin.Text, txbSenha.Text);
        if (controle.mensagem.Equals(""))
        {
            if (controle.tem)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logado com sucesso", "Entrando", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                V7sMain v7 = new V7sMain();
                v7.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha estão incorretos", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
 public bool tem;
    public String mensagem = "";
    public bool acessar(String login, String senha)
    {
        LogindaoComandos loginDao = new LogindaoComandos();
        loginDao.verificarLogin(login, senha);
        if (!loginDao.mensagem.Equals(""))
        {
            this.mensagem = loginDao.mensagem;
        }
        return tem;
    }
    public String cadastrar(String email, String senha, String confSenha)
    {
        return mensagem;
    }
}
```

}

No SQL SERVER :

```
create table logins (
```

email varchar(50),
senha varchar(15)
)

select * from logins

insert into logins values
('maria@gmail.com','12346'),
('joao@gmail.com','12346'),
('vitor@gmail.com','12346'),
('vtr7','1234');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira, procurando somente o usuário, e ao encontrar, voce verifica se a senha dele está correta.

```
try
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email = @login", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["senha"].ToString() == senha)
            {
                result = "logado com sucesso."
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Senha inválida!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Usuário não encontrado!";
        }
      }
}
```